# Xcode organizer hangs after choosing code signing identity

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to distribute an ipa via Testflight and am having real trouble with Xcode (4.3).

The archive seems to build ok but when I go through the enterprise distribution process in the organizer, after selecting the code signing identity (I'm using settings that have previously worked) Xcode just hangs with the "processing" circle animation running.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: With a 200 Mb app, this process takes 15 minutes, with an excellent uplink connection (10mbps upload). So, maybe your hang is just a slow server on the receiving end. Check to see if there is some data packets flowing to and from on your internet connexion. If there is, just be patient (very).

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted your xcode/mac ? most often such issues are solved with this thumb rule.

workaround (not a solution)
If that doesn't solve it, assuming the build runs on your device and only archiving is the issue, drag and drop that build (usually in the products folder in the XCode Project Navigator) into your device (through iTunes) and then copy the ipa created for that app and submit that to TestFlight.